# difference between scriptrunconfig, runconfig and estimator

Tags: azure, data-science, azureml-python-sdk

I just starting learning Machine learning with azure.
I have read a few docs about the difference between scriptrunconfig,  runconfig and estimator.
I didn't understand much about them in any of the doc. please help me understand them.
when do we use each one and why???

Answer (score 1):

Although all three mentioned methods are used for configuring a training job via the Azure ML SDK, please know that `ScriptRunConfig` is the recommended option going forward to simplify the job configuration process.

As clarified in the docs:

> [Estimators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-core/azureml.train.estimator?view=azure-ml-py) are deprecated with the `1.19.0` release of the Python SDK.
> You should also generally avoid explicitly instantiating a
> RunConfiguration object yourself, and instead configure your job using
> the ScriptRunConfig class.

Also, Azure Machine Learning [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-set-up-training-targets) and [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples) have been updated to use `ScriptRunConfig` for job configuration and submission to address this ambiguity and inconsistency with multiple options.

Here is a helper doc to guide through the migration process: [Migrating from Estimators to ScriptRunConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-migrate-from-estimators-to-scriptrunconfig)

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft hasn't updated all the trainings documents. For example, you can see Microsoft still uses Runconfig  in the mslearn-dp100 repository (08 - Create a Pipeline) as follows:
pipeline_run_config = RunConfiguration()

Comment: @user3665906 Please report it as a [new issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/mslearn-dp100/issues/new) for the repo owners to action on. :)